# mypy types issue - Possible overload variant

Tags: python, type-hinting, mypy

I seem to get errors with the following piece of code using mypy

```
payload = {
    'flag': 'good'
}
payload = payload['flag']
scheme: Dict[str, Dict[str, str]] = {
    'a_string': {
        'status': 'abc_string'
    }
}

scheme.get(payload).get('status')
```

or

```
payload = {
    'flag': 'good'
}
payload = payload['flag']
scheme = {
    'a_string': {
        'status': 'abc_string'
    }
}

scheme.get(payload).get('status')
```

I get the following error:

error: No overload variant of "get" of "Mapping" matches argument type "Dict[str, Any]"
            scheme.get(payload).get('status')

But when the types are this:

```
payload = {
    'flag': 'good'
}
payload = payload['flag']
scheme: Dict = {
    'a_string': {
        'status': 'abc_string'
    }
}

scheme.get(payload).get('status')
```

It works fine.

Why does this behaviour happen?

Comment: What's `payload` here?

Comment: just edited it and added it.

Answer (score 2):

You should check all the errors raised by mypy.

```
src/test.py:5: error: Incompatible types in assignment (expression has type "str", variable has type "Dict[str, str]")
src/test.py:12: error: No overload variant of "get" of "Mapping" matches argument type "Dict[str, str]"
src/test.py:12: note: Possible overload variant:
src/test.py:12: note:     def get(self, key: str) -> Optional[Dict[str, str]]
src/test.py:12: note:     <1 more non-matching overload not shown>
```

Note how it complains on line 5 with `Incompatible types in assignment`.

You should change your code to something like:

```
flag = payload['flag']
...
scheme.get(flag).get('status')
```

but then mypy will complain with:

```
src/test.py:12: error: Item "None" of "Optional[Dict[str, str]]" has no attribute "get"
```

indicating that you may be calling `get` on `None`, which happens because `scheme.get(flag)` returns an `Optional`.

Comment: Maybe this helps someone, the key point for me was that I might be calling`.get()` on `None`, which was impossible in reality, but MyPy can't handle reassignments that well, so making it explicit by wrapping it all in `dict()` worked for me. For example: `config = dict(config if config else {})`